# Is the mechanic really Thor in "Adventures in Babysitting" (1987)?

Tags: plot-explanation, adventures-in-babysitting

Was the mechanic actually supposed to be Thor? Or was the little girl just delusional and mistaken?

It's kind of implied that he actually was Thor, since he said he already had a Thor helmet at home. Also, the fact that he got pissed at Brad for saying Thor was a homo implies that he was actually Thor. And also the fact that he responds, "You're welcome", to the little girl, saying, "Thanks, Thor", implying that he is in fact Thor.

Answer (score 6):

I hate to break this to you, but Sarah is simply delusional. There's no good indication that this is a world in which the real Thor (e.g. the Marvel superhero that she idolises) actually exists.

The [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/710599) and [script](https://thescriptlab.com/wp-content/uploads/scripts/23257-Adventures-In-Babysitting-by-David-Simkins.pdf) give us a bit more info about Mr Dawson's thought process. He's very much the curmudgeon, but his heart swells three sizes when he's offered *a gift* by the little girl.

> She held the winged helmet up to him, having to stand on her tiptoes. “Here, take mine.”
> Dawson hesitated.
> “Go on,” she said. “Take it.”
> “Y-you're giving me this?” he asked. “For nothing?”
> “You're my hero!”
> Overcome with warmth, Dawson reached down and took the helmet. He looked at it, touched, then reached into his pocket. He pulled out the car keys and flipped them to Chris.
> “Go on,” he said. “Take the car.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Adventures in Babysitting: Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/710599)</sup></sub>

and

> Dawson TAKES the helmet. He is overcome with WARMTH. He STARES
> at the winged helmet. TOUCHED.
>
> Dawson PAUSES. He reaches into his pocket and REMOVES the car
> keys and TOSSES them to Chris. TEARS well up in his eyes.
>
> <sub><sup>[Adventures in Babysitting: Script](https://thescriptlab.com/wp-content/uploads/scripts/23257-Adventures-In-Babysitting-by-David-Simkins.pdf)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

I really think that it's deliberately ambiguous. The [Ambiguous Santa](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SantaAmbiguity) is a common trope in Christmas stories (including *Home Alone* by the same director). This movie substitutes a different mythological hero, but it's the same trope otherwise. The point of the trope is that it shouldn't matter whether he's the "real" Thor or not, if his deeds merit the appellation.

Comment: It's not ambiguous at all. She idolises the Marvel superhero that she sees in her cartoon shows, not a real flesh-and-blood man

Comment: She's literally dressed as [The Mighty Thor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdL1Iqakdiw) from the the Marvel TV show of the same name *"Upstairs in her bedroom, Sarah lay on the floor, painting a picture of her favorite cartoon hero: Thor, God of Thunder. There were already at least twenty or thirty painted pictures of Thor hanging on her walls. Thor, not unlike Sarah herself, always wore a Viking helmet and a cape. He also always carried a great steel hammer as a weapon. Rather like Sarah's plastic one.*"

Comment: And the the movie explicitly credits the Marvel Thor - **"‘The Mighty Thor’ ™ & © 1987 Marvel Entertainment Group, Inc".**

Comment: @Valorum I agree she's a fan of the Marvel Thor. I don't understand how that bears on my answer. Ambiguous Santa generally looks more like Thomas Nast's Santa than the historical Saint Nicholas, whether he's real or not.

Comment: It's relevant because this film is set in a fictional universe that is, in most ways, like our own. Thor, in this world (and in this fictional universe), is a cartoon character and not a real person. There's no ambiguity here. He's just a guy that a little girl mistakes for someone else.

Comment: @Valorum I feel like you're missing the point of the trope.